# Calculate $x$ [exponential equation]

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Calculate $x$ $$x^{x^x}=2^{-\sqrt{2}}$$

Attemp: [image]

Correct?

Comment: That is indeed a solution. Now you should argue about existence or otherwise of positive real numbers $\alpha\ne\frac14$ such that $\alpha^{\alpha^\alpha}=2^{-\sqrt2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have done with your algebraic manipulations is shown that $x=1/4$ is a solution. You haven't shown, however, that it is the *only* solution.

This can be shown easily: the function $x\mapsto x^{x^x}$ on $[0,\infty)$ is strictly increasing, so attains each positive value at most once.